# Multiple foreign keys on single column

Tags: foreign-key, normalization

I have a table `Item` with many items of many types. Differently typed items are linked to different resources each of whom have a table with primary key.

Currently to achieve this I have two columns in `Item` table: `Resource type` and `Resource ID`.

The question is, what would be propper way to refactor `Item` table in a way so I can set up foreign keys to `Resource ID`?

Preferably without creating many new tables just for this reason or without adding many new columns to `Item` table, where most of them would be empty.

****EDIT****

*Additional note:* aside from resource id's, all items also have multiple other fields, some of which may be used only by some `Resource type`.

As far as I have looked it up, I am seeing 4 options:

1. Have a table `Item` with columns `Resource type` and `Resource ID` as well as all additional columns (case explained above).

   - (+) smaller amount of unused cells
   - (-) some unused cells
   - (-) no foreign keys on `Resource ID`
2. Have a table `Item` with additional column for each `Resource type` as well as all additional common columns.

   - (+) availability of foreign keys on `Resource ID`
   - (-) a lot of unused cells
3. Have a table `Item` with only common columns (or even with only `Item ID`) + additional table with columns: `ID`, `Item ID`, `Value type`, `Value BIGINT`, `Value INT`, `Value STRING`. Second table will be used for `Resource ID`'s as well as fields that are unique for one or another `Resource type`.

   - (+) smaller and constant amount of unused cells
   - (+/-) more space per unique field, but overall smaller than in other cases.
   - (-) no foreign keys on `Resource ID`
4. New table for each `Resource type`

   - (+) availability of foreign keys on `Resource ID`
   - (+) more control over each `Resource type`
   - (-) a lot of new tables, number of which will increase as new `Resource type`'s will be introduced.

I am now evaluating, which of these cases will be more beneficial to my case.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Erik - It should work with different database engines, so it shouldn't be based on some engine specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was decided to go with something between second and third options - adding additional table with columns `Value type` and separate columns for each `Resource type`.

- (+) easier to manage in code
- (+) availability of Foreign Keys on `Resource ID`
- (+) no overhead on table count
- (+) ability to add multiple different `Resource type`'s to each `Item`
- (-) uses extra space for each unused `Resource type` for each field
- (-) lacks ability to *cascade delete* related `Item`, when resource with `Resource ID` is deleted.